# How can we Create JavaScript Objects which has functions

Tags: javascript, function, object

```
var cars = {
    "c1":"BMW", 
    "c2":"Volvo", 
    "c3":["Saab","jas"], 
    "c4":{"Ford":"cdsnj", "Ford1":"cdsnj", "Ford2":"cdsnj"}
    "myMethod" = () =>{
        console.log("eFNJVSL")
    },
};
```

[The way I tried](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hb2c3.png)

Comment: `=` should be `:`

Comment: [Working with objects - JavaScript | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects)

Comment: You're also missing a `,` after the `c4` definition.

Comment: If you want an arrow function, then as the others have said, you just use `:` rather than `=`; it's still a property initializer, doesn't matter what the *value* of the property is, it still comes after `:`, not `=`. If it doesn't need to be an arrow function, you could use [method syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Method_definitions): `myMethod() { /*...*/ }`. (There's also no need for your property names to be in double quotes. It's fine if they are, but all of the ones you've shown are valid identifiers, so you don't need the quotes.)

Answer (score -1):

Replace the `=` with `:`

```js
var cars = {
    "c1":"BMW", 
    "c2":"Volvo", 
    "c3":["Saab","jas"], 
    "c4":{"Ford":"cdsnj", "Ford1":"cdsnj", "Ford2":"cdsnj"},
    "myMethod" : () =>{
        console.log("eFNJVSL")
    },
};
```

Comment: Why does this deserve an answer instead of a comment and a "just a typo" close vote?